# setting values to extend class not working in php

Tags: php, oop

I have some troubles when I create a new object in the "comun" class, it pass thought the parent class but always show the propierty "departamento" as a NULL value

I have tried everything to solve this problem but i couldn't.
i think this is a simple typo error

Modulo class:

```
<?php

class Modulo
{

  protected $cod;
  protected $nombre;
  protected $horas;
  protected $curso;
  protected $plazas;
  protected $ciclo;

  public function __construct($row)
  {

    $this->cod = $row['cod'];
    $this->nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $this->horas = $row['horas'];
    $this->curso = $row['curso'];
    $this->plazas = $row['plazas'];
    $this->ciclo = $row['ciclo'];
  }
//Some getter and setter code
}
```

Comun class:

```
<?php

class Comun extends Modulo
{
  private $departamento;

  public function __construc($row)
  {
    parent::__construc($row);
    $this->departamento = setDepartamento($row['departamento']);
  }

  public function setDepartamento($departamento)
  {
    $this->departamento = $departamento;
  }
}
```

HTML and result
the "departamento" always is ahowing a NULL value

```
<?php
require 'clases/DB.php';
require 'clases/comun.php';

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
  echo $_POST['departamento'];
  $departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
  $moduloComun = new Comun($_POST);
  //$moduloComun->setDepartamento($departamento);

  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($moduloComun);
  echo "</pre>";

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Altas de modulos comunes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Insercion de modulos comunes</h1>
  <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cod"  placeholder="Codigo del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre"  placeholder="Nombre del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="number" name="horas"  placeholder="Horas del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="number" name="curso"  placeholder="Curso del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="number" name="plazas"  placeholder="Plazas del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="ciclo"  placeholder="Ciclo del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="departamento"  placeholder="Departamento del modulo" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar!">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for solve if yo can :)

Comment: you have a major typo; being `construc`.

Comment: *"i think this is a simple typo error"* - Yes, you are right and this is off-topic as a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems  here:

```
public function __construc($row)
{
    parent::__construc($row);
    $this->departamento = setDepartamento($row['departamento']);
}
```

The name of the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor) is always `__construct()`. Because your method is named incorrectly it doesn't work as a constructor and it is not called.

Of course, the constructor of the parent class must be invoked using `parent::__construct()`.

There is no function named `setDepartamento()`. There is a method named `setDepartamento()` in class `Comun`. I guess this is what you wanted but instance methods are always called using an instance (`$this` in your case).

The method `Comun::setDepartamento()` does not return anything. If you assign the value it returns (i.e. `NULL`) to `$this->departamento` it ruins all what the method does.

As an improvement, if `$row` is an array (it looks like it is), use [type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (aka "type hints") to tell the interpreter what kind of values to expect when the function is called. It triggers a fatal error if the function is called with arguments of wrong type and this helps you catch logic errors faster.

The code should be:

```
public function __construct(array $row)
{
    parent::__construct($row);
    $this->setDepartamento($row['departamento']);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is Error in magic function in class Comun, always use parent conctructor.

```
public function __construc($row)
```

need

```
public function __construct(row)
```